# How to put date on barplot() x-axis?

Tags: r, date, bar-chart, axis

```
>dates
"2020-10-03" "2020-10-04" "2020-10-21"
>class(dates)
[1] "Date"

values= c(110,90,90)
cols=ifelse(values>=0,"green","red")
barplot(height = values, width = dates,col = cols, xlab = "values") # error here
```

Error in Ops.Date(space, mean(width)) : * not defined for "Date" objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier option is `formula` method

```
barplot(values ~ dates, col = cols, xlab = "values")
```

-output

[image]

---

According to `?barplot`, both 'height', 'width' are `vector` and `Date` is a vector with some attributes.  So, if we convert to `vector` with `as.numeric`, it would work

```
barplot(height = values, width = as.numeric(dates),col = cols, xlab = "values")
```

#### data

```
dates <- structure(c(18538, 18539, 18556), class = "Date")
```