# Add dates in the X-axis of the R barplot

Tags: r, plot, time-series, bar-chart

I have an R data.frame with two columns. The `var` column contains any variable while the `date` column contains a daily sequence of dates. I'm trying to generate a barplot where the variable is plotted on the Y-axis and the dates on the X-axis.

Since there are too many dates, it would be convenient to add the 1st day of each month. However I am unable to add the dates to the X axis.

Here is a small example:

```
# Example data
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  var = runif(n=365, min=1, max=20),
  date = seq(from=as.Date('2022-01-01'), to=as.Date('2022-12-31'), by=1)
)

# Plot
barplot(df$var, main="var: random variable",
        col="darkorange", border=NA, las=1)
box()
```

[image]

How can I add the dates at monthly intervals?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64489144/how-to-put-date-on-barplot-x-axis

Comment: @MrFlick so it is a dupe?

Comment: @zx8754 I think you're right; the use of `barplot.formula` reduces the complexity of the problem of too-many-labels, though manual use of `axis` allows us to include axis tick marks (which is not friendly using `barplot.formula`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options:

## ggplot2

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(date, var)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="darkorange")
  ### or
  # geom_col()
```

[image: ggplot2 with date on the x-axis]

If you want to play with the x-axis formatting (e.g., change from `"%m %Y"` to something else, or change the count or placement of labels), use `scale_x_date(..)`.

## base R, manual axis

Use `axis`.

```r
bp <- barplot(df$var, main="var: random variable",
              col="darkorange", border=NA, las=1)
box()
```

We can then add things to the plot and/or axis. Unfortunately ... once "gotcha" with this approach is that the x-axis is not simply `1:length(df$var)` as one would hope. If you look at the `bp` object, you'll see it's a matrix (as many rows as `length(df$var)`), where the value is the x-axis position. Note that it starts before 1 and well after `nrow(df)`:

```r
head(bp); tail(bp)
#      [,1]
# [1,]  0.7
# [2,]  1.9
# [3,]  3.1
# [4,]  4.3
# [5,]  5.5
# [6,]  6.7
#         [,1]
# [360,] 431.5
# [361,] 432.7
# [362,] 433.9
# [363,] 435.1
# [364,] 436.3
# [365,] 437.5
```

For this, we can use these values in our positioning of the dates.

```r
ind <- seq(1, nrow(df), length.out = 5)
axis(1, bp[ind,], labels = df$date[ind])
```

[image: base R plot with dates on x-axis]

The use of `13` and `5` are completely arbitrary, up to your preference and the data size.

You have full control over the text with the `labels=` argument. For instance, one could come closer to the default ggplot formatting with

```r
axis(1, bp[ind,], labels = format(df$date[ind], format = "%b %Y"))
```

## base R, automatic x-axis labels

Use formulas, as shown in [How to put date on barplot() x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64489144/3358272):

```r
barplot(var ~ date, data=df, main="var: random variable",
          col="darkorange", border=NA, las=1)
box()
```

[image: base R plot with more-direct date labels]

Note that this does not add ticks to the axis. One can add them with `axis.lty=1`, but you get a trick for each bar, not useful with this data.

Comment: I would just suggest `geom_col()` rather than `geom_bar(stat="identity")`

Comment: @r2evans I understand the logic behind your solution, but the date 2022-12-31 appears shifted to the left. shouldn't it be more to the right? Near the end of the series.

Comment: Good catch, see my edit. (I "dislike" `barplot` in a sense due to this, but it's base and simple.) @sermomon