# X-axis of dates shifted to left in R barplot

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have an R data.frame with two columns. The `var` column contains any variable while the `date` column contains a daily sequence of dates. I'm trying to generate a barplot where the variable is plotted on the Y-axis and the dates on the X-axis.

Since there are too many dates, it would be convenient to add the 1st day of each month. I am doing the following:

```
# Example data
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  var = runif(n=365, min=1, max=20),
  date = seq(from=as.Date('2021-01-01'), to=as.Date('2021-12-31'), by=1)
)

# Plot
barplot(df$var, 
        col="darkorange", border=NA, las=1, xaxt='n',
        main="var: random variable")
dts <- seq(from=as.Date(df$date[1]), to=as.Date(df$date[nrow(df)]), by="months")
ind <- c()
for(d in 1:length(dts)){
  m <- match(dts[d], df$date)
  ind <- c(ind, m)
}
axis(1, at=ind, labels=df$date[ind])
box()
```

[image]

However, the X-axis ticks are clearly shifted to the left. If you look at the last tick (representing "2021-12-01") it should appear almost at the end.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Note that `match` is vectorized, so you can use `ind <- match(dts, df$date)` without any loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

According to this post [How to put date on barplot() x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64489144/how-to-put-date-on-barplot-x-axis) using formula method is an easier option. We still have to consider the and tweak the `width`:

Now there is no left shift!

```
# Example data
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  var = runif(n=365, min=1, max=20),
  date = seq(from=as.Date('2021-01-01'), to=as.Date('2021-12-31'), by=1)
)

# Plot

barplot(df$var ~ df$date, col = "darkorange",
        border=NA, las=1, xaxt='n', width = 0.8,
        main="var: random variable", xlab = "date", ylab="var")

dts <- seq(from=as.Date(df$date[1]), to=as.Date(df$date[nrow(df)]), by="months")
ind <- c()
for(d in 1:length(dts)){
  m <- match(dts[d], df$date)
  ind <- c(ind, m)
}
axis(1, at=ind, labels=df$date[ind])
box()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this resolve the issue? OP simulates a whole year of data, and your plot, according the the labels, doesn't even make it to April. And also appears to have bars before 2021-01-01, which is the earliest date in the data.

Comment: At `?barplot` the `width` argument description says *"Specifying a single value will have no visible effect unless `xlim` is specified."* That seems incorrect based on your answer. Might be worth a documentation bug report.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to fix your plot in base graphics, but I can show a simple ggplot version:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = var)) +
  geom_col(fill = "darkorange") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month") +
  labs(title = "var: random variable") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]